# @Html.ValidationMessage adding prepending field. to key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, validationmessage

I am trying to use `@Html.ValidationMessage` like the following:

```
@Html.TextBox(Model.Key, "", attr)
@Html.ValidationMessage(Model.Key)
```

However, my validation message isn't displaying.

If I print my `Model.Key` to the screen, I get "FirstName", however if I look at the source that is created for the above code, it creates it like this:

```
<input name="FirstName" class="form__control" data-msg-maxlength="This field is limited to 200 characters" data-rule-maxlength="200" data-rule-required="true" id="FirstName" placeholder="Please enter your first name" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="field.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Does anyone know why it is prepending the `field.` to that validation message span or how I can get rid of it?

I have tried typing it in manually:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName")
```

And this still seems to prepend the `field.`

**Update**

Could it be something to do with me using `@Html.EditorFor(_ => field)` to call a partial that has the textbox and validation message? - If I put the `ValidationMessage` next to the `EditorFor` then it works properly (but is out of position)

Comment: Do you have a [Required] in the model?

Comment: No, I create the model error manually: ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "Error");

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do the editorfor bit in a loop: 
                            `@foreach (var field in group.FieldGroup)
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(_ => field)
                            }`

Comment: Then that's you problem. And it will create others problems such as not being able to bind to your model. You need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks @StephenMuecke, I will close as duplicate

Answer (score -1):

**just do like this**

```
public class A
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: look like its true.